# Passing data between Microsoft Virtual Assistant and Skills

Tags: azure, .net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services

I have CalendarSkill connected with my Virtual Assistant and its working fine. Instead of using Authentication Prompt I am generating Graph token in my Virtual Assistant and want to pass the same to the Skill. How can I pass the data to skillContext or maybe use slots (not sure how to retrieve or sent data using these slots).

I have tried passing data using DialogOptions but how to retrieve that data in skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dialog you are trying to retrieve the options in is a `WaterfallDialog` you can retrieve the options using the [`Options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.waterfallstepcontext.options?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) property, as you have already mentioned you pass the options in using the [`options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.begindialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) parameter.

How this looks is:

```
// Call the dialog and pass through options
await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MyDialog), new { MyProperty1 = "MyProperty1Value", MyProperty2 = "MyProperty2Value" });

// Retrieve the options
public async Task<DialogTurnResult> MyWaterfallStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var passedInOptions = waterfallStepContext.Options;

    ...
}
```

I would recommend using a strongly typed class for passing in and retrieving the options, so you could create something which looks like the following:

```
// Concrete class definition
public class MyOptions
{
    public string MyOptionOne { get; set; }
    public string MyOptionTwo { get; set; }
}

// Passing options to Dialog
await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MyDialog), new MyOptions{ MyOptionOne = "MyOptionOneValue", MyOptionTwo = "MyOptionTwo" });

// Retrieving options in child Dialog
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public async Task<DialogTurnResult> MyWaterfallStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext waterfallStepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var passedInOptions = waterfallStepContext.Options;
    // Get passed in options, need to serialise the object before we deserialise because calling .ToString on the object is unreliable
    MyOptions passedInMyOptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyOptions>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(waterfallStepContext.Options));
    ...

    // Use retrieved options like passedInOptions.MyOptionOne etc
}
```

Comment: This works fine when we are in same bot. So when I am sending control to the another skill, lets say I want to check my meetings. It sends request to the calendar skill and check for authentication, if token is not present it will prompt authentication dialog. So I am checking waterfallContext for any options but its not there.

Comment: @ShubhamBindal you are correct, I managed to find [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/1d7726a6d1469e1d8c8f61355cd31119f378cb97/specs/manifest/botframework-manifest.md#slots) spec definition along with [this manifest example](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/cfa1b5010ffa8b4fb3e7b7ec9aabad72ad9f3734/specs/manifest/example.man#L28). I couldn't find any end-to-end example even after searching the botframework-solutions, botframework-sdk, and botbuilder-samples repos on the Microsoft GitHub account.

Comment: I did find [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/commit/02c397167386888ba77a70b19f503c4014c8dd80#diff-a022cee341f24942220d324739d121af) where support for slots was added, then [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/740) about a week later saying that the code was going to be retired. You could try opening an issue on the [botframework-solutions](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions) repo where there docs for the virtual assistant and skills are maintained.

Comment: After reading slots here I believe it is mainly for the LUIS entities so I should not touch it for sending custom data but the issue I am facing I dont think its issue with bot framework, its my lack of knowledge in how request works. Please check this piece of code I think you will be able to figure out.

Comment: From VA - 
`await dc.BeginDialogAsync(identifiedSkill.Id, new { SkillToken = "TestToken" });

                // Pass the activity we have
                var result = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

                if (result.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Complete)
                {
                    await CompleteAsync(dc);
                }`

Comment: In Calendar: 
`var response = sc.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
                response.Type = ActivityTypes.Event;
                response.Name = "Tokens/request";

                // Send the tokens/request Event
                await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync(response);

                return await sc.PromptAsync(nameof(MultiProviderAuthDialog), new PromptOptions());
`

Comment: Instead of this sc.PromptAsync, how can I send the DialogTurnResult to VA and there I can handle this and send the value back.
Something like that,

Comment: Try the [`EndDialogAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.enddialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogContext_EndDialogAsync_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) or [`ReplaceDialogAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.replacedialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_DialogContext_ReplaceDialogAsync_System_String_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) methods on the `WaterfallStepContext`.

Comment: Depending on your scenario, I think EndDialogAsync is probably what you want. Both of them allow for an `object` to be passed in - "Ends a dialog by popping it off the stack and returns an optional result to the dialog's parent." and "Ends the active dialog and starts a new dialog in its place. This is particularly useful for creating loops or redirecting to another dialog.".

Comment: Found it. Yes, instead of endDialogAsync, `return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);` and then passed the values in Activity from Virtual Assistant. Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: It would be great if you posted the relevant code for the VA and the Skill for anyone who comes across this question in the future.